# python selenium find image captcha whit NoName

Tags: python, selenium

I need to take screenshot and crop image, the problem is i don't know how i can find this image/captcha of this page gmail.it/freemail/request/new

Im try this code but not working, locate the first element :

```
elem = driver.find_element_by_class_name('formfield')
```

How i can locate the captcha image ?

Comment: It's not easy to "mess" with google. You'd need a trained captcha computer vision bot.

Comment: need only locate this image, no more

Comment: `driver.find_element_by_class_name('formfield').find_element_by_anchor_name('img')`?